# SQL CASE isNumeric with multiple values?

Tags: mysql, sql, case, isnumeric

I have an instance where sometimes we aren't sure to filter by the name text or the name id. I've solved this with a case statement and `isnumeric`. For example, we have both the id and name values but we're not sure which column is being asked to filter. `rtresource.id` is numeric, and in this case we have the value `'183'` to work with. If `rtresource.rname (varchar)` is trying to filter, then we have the rname for that id 'Jane Thompson'.

**So the filter is either**

```
rtresource.id=183
```

**Or**

```
rtresource.rname='Jane Thompson'
```

**Instead becomes**

```
rtresource.rname in (CASE IsNumeric(rtresource.rname) WHEN 1 then '183' else 'Jane Thompson' End)
```

This works awesome. The issue is having more than one set of id/rname being passed. Typically, we would ask either `rtresource.id in (183, 23) or  rtresource.rname in ('Jane Thompson','John Doe')`. How can I solve this with a case statement?

```
rtresource.rname in (CASE IsNumeric(rtresource.rname) WHEN 1 then ('183','23') else ('Jane Thompson','John Doe') End)
```

Above complains over the commas between values. I've also tried:

```
rtresource.rname in (CASE IsNumeric(rtresource.rname) WHEN 1 then ('183'+','+'23') else ('Jane Thompson'+','+'John Doe') End)
```

Which doesn't work either. Ideas? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: `rtresource.id in (183, 23) or  rtresource.rname in ('Jane Thompson','John Doe')` ..does this not work as a filter? why would you need a `case` expression?

Comment: I'm really surprised that "this works awesome", because your question is tagged MySQL and there is no `IsNumeric()` function in MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff..it is `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

You have to repeat the `case` for every value in the list:

```
where rtresource.rname in (
  CASE IsNumeric(rtresource.rname) WHEN 1 then '183' else 'Jane Thompson' End,
  CASE IsNumeric(rtresource.rname) WHEN 1 then '23' else 'John Doe' End
)
```

or since the values don't intersect, just:

```
where rtresource.rname in (183, 23, 'Jane Thompson', 'John Doe')
```

which would perform much better as it will use an index (if any) of the column, and is easier to code, understand and scale.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Skip the case and instead:

(IsNumeric(rtresource.rname) = 1 and rtresource.rname in ('183','23'))
or
(IsNumeric(rtresource.rname) != 1 and rtresource.rname in ('Jane Thompson','John Doe'))